# Finding $a,b$ so that $f(x)=x^2|x-2|+a|x+b|$ be differentiable at every points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The function  $f(x)=x^2|x-2|+a|x+b|$ is differentiable at every points. what is the value of $a+b$ ?

$1)2\qquad\qquad2)-2\qquad\qquad3)-6\qquad\qquad4)-4$

I know a function that contains absolute bars, is usually discontinues  at the root of the expression inside the absolute value bar. So here the points $x=2$ and $x=-b$ cause the problem.
After plugging in numbers luckily I realized that for $b=-2$ and $a=-4$ we can factor the expression as $f(x)=(x+2)(x-2)|x-2|$ so I think it is the third choice.

My question is how to solve the problem without guessing numbers?

Comment: @Sid Not JEE. but another exam similar to it called Konkour.

Comment: @Sid Questions are in Persian language(not English). but anyway, Can you reach this site ? https://irmohasel.com/%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%DA%A9%D9%86%DA%A9%D9%88%D8%B1/

Answer (score 1):

You can prove $b=-2$ to justify your answer. Your motivation for trying to prove this is that otherwise $f$ has two problem points like you mentioned, and two problem points is harder to handle than one.

If $b \ne -2,$ then $x^2|x-2|$ is differentiable at $x=-b,$ so so is $f(x)-x^2|x-2|=a|x+b|,$ implying $a=0,$ but this doesn't work.

If $b=-2,$ factor as $(x^2+a)|x-2|.$ You can prove $x^2+a$ has a zero at $2,$ which implies $a=-4.$